# R: Cannot install igraph package

Tags: r, package, igraph, installation-package

I've been trying installing R package `igraph` but during installation I keep receiving the following error:

```
** libs
gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fpic  -g -O2  -c AMD/Source/amd.f -o AMD/Source/amd.o
make: gfortran: No such file or directory
make: *** [/usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf:191: AMD/Source/amd.o] Error 127
```

I've tried both installing from CRAN and from github repository with the same result. It seems that during installation there is an error on level of compiling C `igraph` library. I've also tried pre-compiling it but it doesn't work. File `AMD/Source/amd.f` is present in `igraph` repository.

Here is my `sessionInfo`:

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Manjaro Linux

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/libblas.so.3.9.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3.9.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=pl_PL.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=pl_PL.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=pl_PL.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=pl_PL.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.3 tools_3.6.3
```

I'd be grateful for any suggestion.

Comment: `gfortran: No such file or directory` would certainly break things. Do you have it installed? For me (ubuntu), it's `apt-get install gfortran`, but I'm not as familiar with majaro or arch. Perhaps this helps? https://forum.manjaro.org/t/installing-and-using-fortran-compiler/27638

Comment: @r2evans oh, thanks for your suggestion. I was so stupid not having checked it earlier. I thought this error message indicates that there is no file to compile... But you're right, I just had no compiler installed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @r2evans suggested in his comment, the answer is simple: I needed to install `gfortran`, I had misunderstood the error message... That's all folks!